# \page after each item with \setupitemize

Tags: context

I would like to force a page break after each level 1 item of my presentations. How should I set \setupitemize ?
This MWE fails :

```
%\startmode[screen]
\setuppapersize[S6]
\setupitemize[1][standard][inbetween={\page}]
%\stopmode

\starttext
\startitemize[n]
\startitem \input knuth \stopitem
\startitem \input ward \stopitem    
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but what if you remove the `[standard]` key in your setup? Do you get page breaks as you want?

Comment: @mickep. Thanks, if I change [standard] and set to [section], I achieve what I want. Do you want to convert your comment to an answer, or shall I self-answer it ?

Comment: As I am still not sure about what the problem is and what your solution actually does, I suggest that you do it (but I am happy it solved your problem!).

Comment: The `standard` option changes the argument of the `before`, `after` and `inbetween` key to `\blank`. This overwrites your manual setting for `inbetween` key and you get just a blank line between the item entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get no page break between the items in your example because you pass the `standard` option to the environment. The result of the `standard` option is to set the arguments of the `before`, `after` and `inbetween` key to `\blank` which overwrites your own setting for the `inbetween` key.

Since you don’t want the effect of `standard` in your document you can just drop the third argument of `\setupitemize` and use the following setup:

```
\setupitemize [1] [inbetween=\page]
```